# Why pulled image is smaller than original image from the private registry?

Tags: docker

The size of the image `suse/sles12` is 258.3MB in the registry, but it is only 258.2MB after I pull it. Why?

**private registry:**

```
jya@controller:~$ docker images |grep suse
opensuse                                       latest               7617deda9fe6        11 weeks ago        97.7 MB
registry.example.com:5000/suse/sles12                  latest               3f58b8127be2        3 months ago        258.3 MB
```

**localhost:**

```
monkey@monkey-VirtualBox:~$ docker pull registry.example.com:5000/suse/sles12                                      
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from suse/sles12
a3ed95caeb02: Already exists 
5513e1f80831: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:6c04761f63fd827e8f0c251b753b71d24e241276b4defd41a34af39bd71f7fe4
Status: Downloaded newer image for 10.46.169.17:5000/suse/sles12:latest

monkey@monkey-VirtualBox:~$ docker images |grep suse
10.46.169.17:5000/suse/sles12               latest              3f58b8127be2        3 months ago        258.2 MB
```

Comment: I assume this is related to the block size of your docker filesystem (devicemapper, aufs, overlayfs, btrfs, ...)

Comment: Compression, rounding, and measuring only the layers vs including the image config would be my guesses. But given this was asked over 5 years ago, I doubt the OP still has the same issue.